# In implementation inheritance are data members from multiple layers allocated contiguously?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I'm wondering whether or class data members from multiple levels of inheritance are allocated contiguously in C++ compilers. For example if I have the following classes:

```
class Base
{
 public:
   int a;
};

class child_1 : public Base
{
 public:
   int b;
};

class child_2 : public child_1
{
 public:
   int c;
}
```

Will the following operation run and output what is expected on all compilers?

```
child_2 my_obj;

my_obj.a = 3; my_obj.b = 2; my_obj.c = 1;

Base* base_ptr = (Base*)&my_obj;
int* int_ptr = (int*)base_ptr;

cout << "Output 3: " << *int_ptr << endl
     << "Output 2: " << *(int_ptr + 1) << endl;
     << "Output 1: " << *(int_ptr + 2) << endl;
```

Furthermore, if this is possible, do I need an intermediate cast from the child_2* type to the Base* type as I have above or would the following also be permissable?

```
int* int_ptr (int*)&my_obj;
```

Please note that I'm not asking if this is a good idea. Obviously you would want to design your software so that you don't end up doing stuff like this, but I'm considering such an approach to solve a problem with working with some older code (made by an experienced software engineer, which makes it more complicated).

The compiler that I'm specifically working with is VC++ 2005.

Comment: If you ever introduces a `virtual` function, this breaks; if you ever introduces another data member, this breaks; ... Frankly, encapsulation was created for a purpose. If you really want iteration, have a function create an array of `int*` that references the various fields in the order you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the relative layout of derived-class members and base-class members is not specified.

In the current standard, a class is only *standard-layout* if, among other conditions, it:

> either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members

In older standards (which would apply to your compiler), there wasn't even a concept of *standard-layout*, only POD, and any class with a non-empty base class was not POD.

Your code depends on how a particular compiler lays out the base classes, and is not portable.